# getting option value via $_post using foreach loop in php

Tags: php, post, foreach, html-select

I have a simple form which has the following elements

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="add_cust_prces.php">
  <input type="text" name="Code" id="Code" />
  <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" />
  <select name="district">
    <option values=1>District A</option>
    <option values=2>District B</option>
    <option values=3>District C</option>
    <option values=4>District D</option>
    <option values=5>District E</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

now i'm using the following script to retrieve all the values that was submitted by the user (with the help of $_POST) and building a string.

```
$postdata = $_POST;

$sqlbld = "INSERT INTO `customer` (`cst_id`, `cst_code`, `cst_name`, `cst_dist`, `cst_flag`) VALUES (NULL, ";
foreach ($postdata as $key => $value) {
    if($key <> 'button'){       
        if(!is_numeric($value)){
            $sqlbld .= "'$value', ";
        } else {
            $sqlbld .= "$value, ";          
        }
    }       
}

$sqlbld .= "'yes');";
echo $sqlbld;
```

The Problem I am facing is I want the option's "values" to be retrieved instead i get the name of the option.

ex: if i selected the "District B" from the option list i want the value "2" instead i get the name "District B"

please advice

Comment: Shouldn't it be `option value=`? You have an extra s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `value` (not `values`) in your option tags (otherwise the browser will send the text):

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="add_cust_prces.php">
  <input type="text" name="Code" id="Code" />
  <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" />
  <select name="district">
    <option value="1">District A</option>
    <option value="2">District B</option>
    <option value="3">District C</option>
    <option value="4">District D</option>
    <option value="5">District E</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: one character makes a huge difference. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="add_cust_prces.php">

 <input type="text" name="Code" id="Code" />
```

```
<option value="1">District A</option>

<option value="2">District B</option>

<option value="3">District C</option>

<option value="4">District D</option>

<option value="5">District E</option>
```